# How to duplicate rows via pl/sql?

Tags: sql, plsql

what is the best way to copy rows from a table and insert into the same table with some value changed. say i have a table like below. I want to select all the rows with year 2021 and insert into the same table and just switch the year to 2022.
need to do this with pl/sql.

```
id | projects   | year | employeeID

1  | chandra    | 2019 | 7

2  | alphaone   | 2020 | 2

3  | madinc     | 2021 | 3

4  | runa       | 2021 | 1
```

Comment: Is ID definied as an auto incrementing value or should this be duplicated also?

Comment: @stu - id is auto increment

Comment: Why PL/SQL specifically? Can you not just use SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think that id is a serial

so a simple INSERT INTO SELECT is enough

The econf DISTINCT subselect is not necessary if the project exist onl yonce per year

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   "id" SERIAL,
>   "projects" VARCHAR(8),
>   "year" INTEGER,
>   "employeeID" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   ("id", "projects", "year","employeeID")
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'chandra', '2019',7),
>   ('2', 'alphaone', '2020',4),
>   ('3', 'madinc', '2021',2),
>   ('4', 'runa', '2021',1);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 ("projects", "year","employeeID")  SELECT "projects",'2022',"employeeID" FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "projects","employeeID" FROM table1 WHERE "year" = 2021) t1
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECt * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | projects | year | employeeID
> -: | :------- | ---: | ---------:
>  1 | chandra  | 2019 |          7
>  2 | alphaone | 2020 |          4
>  3 | madinc   | 2021 |          2
>  4 | runa     | 2021 |          1
>  1 | madinc   | 2022 |          2
>  2 | runa     | 2022 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a3fcdf373ab4187a1e661ff3da757694)*

Comment: I updated the question, there is one more column employeeid, which is a foreign key from a employee table. i got an error ERROR:  column "employeeId" of relation "Projects" does not exist
LINE 3: insert into "Projects" (id, projects, year, employeeId...
                                       ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 98

Comment: when you add another column, you need to add the new colum name at **three** points see example

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT` can be combined with a `SELECT` query.

For example:

```
insert into t (id, projects, year)
select id, projects, 2022
from t
where year = 2021
```